# React looping hooks to display in other hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a react Web App, and I'm trying to loop a list of objects and output the content to another hook, see below for details.

the issue that I'm facing is when I loop the object, I just get one result.

```
Object.keys(transactions).forEach((key, index) =>
    {output =  <TransactionsItem name={transactions[key].lable} />}
)
```

When I try to concatenate, it doesn't work.

```
Object.keys(transactions).forEach((key, index) =>
    {output = output + <TransactionsItem name={transactions[key].lable} />}
)
```

How can i concatenate ?

**Full info if needed**

**transactionsList hook**

```
const Transactions = () =>{

  var [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

  function TransactionList(props){
    var output
    transactions = props.user.transactions
    Object.keys(transactions).forEach((key, index) =>
      {output =  <TransactionsItem name={transactions[key].lable} />}
    )
    return(output);
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Menu />
          <TransactionList user={user} />
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}
```

TransactionList

```
const TransactionsItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>{props.name}</div>
  );
}
```

Object

```
{
-LqaBL5jD3ktq_duQNH2: {amount: 5, date: "07/10/2019, 23:28:37", lable: "coffee"},
-LqaBLZlT_zGjr9pngWE: {amount: 5, date: "07/10/2019, 23:28:39", lable: "coffee"},
-LqaBLqKtdbp15PGdwDs: {amount: 10, date: "07/10/2019, 23:28:40", lable: "Ride"},
-LqaBM9QiHwUtmNgHN5P: {amount: 10, date: "07/10/2019, 23:28:41", lable: "Lunch"},
-LqfCNGS-4fRbgTZFnn6: {amount: 10, date: "08/10/2019, 22:51:14", lable: "Ride"},
-LqfCONTvk5p0MfK2tGc: {amount: 10, date: "08/10/2019, 22:51:18", lable: "Ride"},
-LqfCOjq1lO9auOnka1S: {amount: 10, date: "08/10/2019, 22:51:20", lable: "Ride"},
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use javascript map instead of forEach,

```
function TransactionList(props){
    var output
    transactions = props.user.transactions
    output = Object.keys(transactions).map((key, index) => <TransactionsItem name={transactions[key].lable} />)
    return(output);
  }
```

Hope the above will work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting one result is because `output = ...` is only assigning the last component to the output variable. Concatenation of objects in Javascript should be done using array methods. Gangadhar's solution should be preferred for conciseness, but if you are unfamiliar with the `Array.map` method, this should be easier to read:

```
function TransactionList(props) {
  var output = []
  var transactions = props.user.transactions
  Object.keys(transactions).forEach((key) =>
    { output.push(<TransactionsItem name={transactions[key].lable} />) }
  )
  return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {

  const [list, setList] = useState(" ");

  const [items, updateOnClick] = useState([ ]);

  function updateList(event) {
    const valueEntered = event.target.value;
    setList(valueEntered);
  }

  function updateClick(){
     updateOnClick(list);
     }
 return (
           <input onChange={updateList} type="text" value={list} />
            <button onClick={updateClick}>
              <span>Add</span>
            </button>
            <div>
              <ul>
                {items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>) }
              </ul>
            </div>);}
export default App;
```

Comment: Here their is an INPUT tag of HTML where whatever value is entered is read by the first hook state and than when "Clicked" on the ADD button the first "State" is saved to other "State" Hook.
    
    Hope this will help.